# Table alignment in IE11

Tags: css, styles, internet-explorer-11

enter image description here I have a table

```
<div id="main" style="margin-left: initial;">
&nbsp; 
&nbsp;
<table id="history_table"   align="center">
....
</table>
</div>
```

I have added some styles to it in the  tag in the html page.

```
#history_table{

    background-color:#CCCCCC;
    border:2px solid black;
    margin-left: initial;
    width=9px;


}
```

The table alignment is proper in chrome while in IE11 it is a little on the right side. Can someone help me to fix this ?

Thanks

[image]
[image]

Comment: The 'initial' value does not seem to be supported by IE, please see http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_initial.asp. This might be why you are getting misalignment. Try margin: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try this:

```
#history_table{
  display:block;
  position:relative;

  background-color:#CCCCCC;
  border:2px solid black;
  margin-left: initial;
  /*width:9px;*/

  width:100%;

 table-layout: fixed; /* Include this code */


}

#history_table td{  
  display:block;
}
```

Comment: That solves but Width i just need 90 %. When i change the width to 90%, the alignment goes wrong.

Comment: Can you show me an example online? Did you give fixed height on TD´s?

Comment: It is actually not live to show it online. Tried to attach fiddle, but it is not working fine. I just want to reduce the width to 90%.

Comment: Still the table goes to the right side. The width gets reduced in the left while I want to reduce it in the right.

Comment: there was one extra align property. I had to remove it to make it work. Thanks.